# Passing file location as a parameter in to File(String) showing error

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

I have properties file where I have specified the file location. In property file below value is given. Below path have 2 text files named 1 and 2.

```
FileLoc="C://users//test"
```

In Java file I have below set of code to fetch and process the info.

```
  public void textFile() {
  Properties p=new Properties();
  p.load(new FileInputStream("data.properties"));
  String path=p.getProperty("FileLoc");
  List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
  File dir = new File(path);
  for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
  if (file.getName().endsWith((".txt"))) {
    textFiles.add(file.getName());
    System.out.println(file.getName());
 }
}
.....
}
```

When I debug i see value given in the properties file assigned to path String but when going in for loop I am getting null pointer exception. If I give the value directly which is in properties file to the file constructor, it is working properly and listing all text files like below

```
File dir = new File("C://users//test");
```

If I print the directory , its showing C:\users\text in both the cases. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hope your properties file do not contain the double quotes... Nor the double slashes...

Comment: yes, you are right. I added double quotes by mistake. Stuck on this for 3 hours and u see this kind of very silly errors. shh...Thanks anyways@UsagiMiyamoto